# Directly Proportional

Tags: arithmetic, definition, ratio

How can I determine if x is directly proportional to y or not?

For,example we know that 2 atoms of Hydrogen(x) combine with 1 atom of Oxygen(y).

How can I establish here that x (number of Hydrogen atoms required) is proportional to y (number of Oxygen atoms)?

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_(mathematics)) says that If one variable is always the product of the other and **a constant**, the two are said to be directly proportional. x and y are directly proportional if the ratio 
y/x is constant.

Answer (score 0):

Constant can be any real number except 0.
And for case of this oxygen and hydrogen ratio $y/x=1/2$